# How to optimize multiple calls to library function (e.g., random.random)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, random, cygwin

Say I want to estimate π using a monte-carlo simulation based on sphere volume (code below).

## Is there a way to optimize the calls to `random.random()`?

```
$ cat pi_estimate.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
The task:
    Consider the part of the sphere x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 for which x,y,z > 0

The calculation:
    We generate n (e.g., 10,000) points (x,y,z) with 0 <= x,y,z <= 1 and using
    the formula for sphere volume: V = (4/3) * PI * r^3, we'll estimate PI.

    The cube in which the sphare resides has a volume: 8 * r^3

    Now, if we only consider the quardant where 0 <= x,y,z <= 1, then it's 
    only 1/8th of the total volumes, namely, Vs = (1/6) * PI * r^3, and 
    Vc = r^3
    As r == 1, Vs = (1/6) * PI, and Vc = 1
    Vs/Vc = (1/6) * PI
    Thus PI = 6 * Vs/Vc

    So, every point (x,y,z) with 0 <= x,y,z <= 1 which is x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 
    is added to Vs (and Vc), and if not than it is only in Vc.
"""

import random

N = 1000000
Vs_counter = 0
for i in xrange(N):
    x = random.random() 
    y = random.random()
    z = random.random()
    if (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) <= 1:
        Vs_counter += 1

pi = 6 * (1.0 * Vs_counter / N)
print "PI is estimated",pi
```

The following profiling indeed shows that the script spends most of its time in `random.random()`:

```
$ python -m cProfile pi_estimate.py
PI is estimated 3.142194
         3000049 function calls in 3.856 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:48(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:74(_Feature)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:75(__init__)
        1    0.007    0.007    0.007    0.007 hashlib.py:55(<module>)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hashlib.py:94(__get_openssl_constructor)
        1    2.822    2.822    3.856    3.856 pi_estimate.py:22(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 random.py:100(seed)
        1    0.030    0.030    0.040    0.040 random.py:40(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:655(WichmannHill)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:72(Random)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:805(SystemRandom)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 random.py:91(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_md5}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha1}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha224}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha256}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha384}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha512}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {binascii.hexlify}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {function seed at 0xffe31e2c}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.exp}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.log}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.sqrt}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  3000000    0.994    0.000    0.994    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
        1    0.002    0.002    0.002    0.002 {posix.urandom}
```

## edit (Thu, Nov 27, 2014 20:45:26)

Since @ch3ka checked his code and demonstrated improvements when using local names for library functions, I decided to check with *my* code.
 In my code, there's no improvement that I can ascertain:

```
$ for i in {1..9} ; do for script in  pi_estimate.py  pi_estimate_local.py  ; do echo $script; python -m cProfile $script | grep 3000000; done; done
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.360    0.000    0.360    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.341    0.000    0.341    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.326    0.000    0.326    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.337    0.000    0.337    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.331    0.000    0.331    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.317    0.000    0.317    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.327    0.000    0.327    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.316    0.000    0.316    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.354    0.000    0.354    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.325    0.000    0.325    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.326    0.000    0.326    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.341    0.000    0.341    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.349    0.000    0.349    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.324    0.000    0.324    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.326    0.000    0.326    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.315    0.000    0.315    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate.py
  3000000    0.358    0.000    0.358    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
pi_estimate_local.py
  3000000    0.324    0.000    0.324    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
```

### Here're the two scripts (I edited out the docstring):

```
$ cat pi_estimate.py | tail -14

import random

N = 1000000
Vs_counter = 0
for i in xrange(N):
    x = random.random() 
    y = random.random()
    z = random.random()
    if (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) <= 1:
        Vs_counter += 1

pi = 6 * (1.0 * Vs_counter / N)
print "PI is estimated",pi

$ cat pi_estimate_local.py | tail -14

from random import random as rnd

N = 1000000
Vs_counter = 0
for i in xrange(N):
    x = rnd()
    y = rnd()
    z = rnd()
    if (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) <= 1:
        Vs_counter += 1

pi = 6 * (1.0 * Vs_counter / N)
print "PI is estimated",pi
```

## edit (Fri, Nov 28, 2014 17:50:09)

Following @ch3ka last three comments, I calculated the 300k calls to random(), and as @ch3ka pointed out, the Python profiler indeed presented a misleading picture. Calling random with a local reference indeed saves time, viz.:

```
$ for i in {1..9}; do python pi_estimate.py ; done
PI is estimated 3.143076  -> execution time: 2.62900018692
PI is estimated 3.143346  -> execution time: 2.58100008965
PI is estimated 3.140286  -> execution time: 2.52200007439
PI is estimated 3.145734  -> execution time: 2.5110001564
PI is estimated 3.140898  -> execution time: 2.51300001144
PI is estimated 3.143058  -> execution time: 2.59200000763
PI is estimated 3.139332  -> execution time: 2.60400009155
PI is estimated 3.142956  -> execution time: 2.47399997711
PI is estimated 3.144552  -> execution time: 2.50100016594

$ for i in {1..9}; do python pi_estimate_local.py ; done
PI is estimated 3.146772  -> execution time: 2.22300004959
PI is estimated 3.142038  -> execution time: 2.18499994278
PI is estimated 3.139032  -> execution time: 2.14800000191
PI is estimated 3.14052  -> execution time: 2.20199990273
PI is estimated 3.141384  -> execution time: 2.25199985504
PI is estimated 3.142086  -> execution time: 2.25200009346
PI is estimated 3.137748  -> execution time: 2.18099999428
PI is estimated 3.141906  -> execution time: 2.40199995041
PI is estimated 3.138126  -> execution time: 2.16100001335
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an optimization technique you can use - local aliasing.

Consider

```
import random
import timeit

try: xrange # py3 compatibility
except NameError: xrange = range

def f1():
    return sum((random.random() for _ in xrange(10**5)))

def f2():
    rand = random.random # bind random.random to local var
    myrange = xrange # same for range gen (kinda pointless here, but to illustrate that you can do this with everything)
    return sum((rand() for _ in myrange(10**5)))

print(timeit.timeit(f1, number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(f2, number=100))
```

`f1` and `f2` do the same thing, right? Except `f2` has the advantage to find the range and the rand function in local namespace, where `f1` has to look up in module namespace - *and* has to do an attribute lookup on `.random`.

So in theory, we should see an advantage here if python does not optimize for this case internally. And in fact, we can, even on py3:

```
ch3ka@x200 /tmp % python2 aliastest.py
1.88513803482
1.4380030632
ch3ka@x200 /tmp % python3 aliastest.py
2.096395079046488
1.6709147160872817
```

So using this technique, you might be able to speed up your program - but then again, this is depending on implementation details.

Note that you could also write `f2` as:

```
def f3(rand = random.random, myrange = xrange):
    return sum((rand() for _ in myrange(10**5)))
```

which will bind the names at function definition time already.
Greatest part of speedup is due to the spared repeated attribute lookups anyway though, I suppose.

Comment: My code is _not_ inside a function. Thus, are you sure your suggestion applies?

Comment: yes, when you alias `random.random` to something local to your module, the same applies when you *repeatedly* call it. It'll save the repeated attribute lookup.

Comment: `ch3ka@x200 /tmp % python2 -m timeit -c 'import random; sum(random.random() for _ in range(10**4))'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.17 msec per loop`
`ch3ka@x200 /tmp % python2 -m timeit -c 'from random import random as r; sum(r() for _ in range(10**4))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 msec per loop`

Comment: `ch3ka@x200 /tmp % python3 -m timeit -c 'import random; sum(random.random() for _ in range(10**4))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.93 msec per loop`
`
`ch3ka@x200 /tmp % python3 -m timeit -c 'from random import random as r; sum(r() for _ in range(10**4))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 msec per loop`

Comment: Unfortunately @ch3ka, when I check with _my_ code, I don't see improvements. See `edit (Thu, Nov 27, 2014 20:45:26)` above. Am I missing something?

Comment: have you done measurements with `time` or python's `timeit.timeit`? You *should* see improvements, but of course not in the profiler - as this just ignores "constants" like attribute lookups.

Comment: @user1656850 as you see, only about of a third of your total runtime is covered by the profiler

Comment: and actually, attribute lookups are pretty costly in python.

Comment: Following your last three comments, I verified (second edit above) that indeed the profiler presents misleading results. Thanks for pointing that out: I'll have to educate myself on these profiler's gotchas.